# Show/Hide Division with 2 Drop-down Lists

Tags: javascript, html

I am totally new for javascript and jquery. Currently I want to create a simple show hide function with 2 drop-down list. I will explain further below the code. If you can, please try the code below, it may help you understand my question better.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

<head>
  <title></title>

<style type="text/css">
.hide {
  display:none;
}
</style>

<script  type="text/javascript">

function PriceCharts(charts1){
 var PriceCharts=charts1.options;
 for (var a=1;a<=500;a++){
  if (document.getElementById(PriceCharts[a].value)){
   document.getElementById(PriceCharts[a].value).style.display=PriceCharts[a].selected?'block':'none';
  }
 }
}

function IndicatorCharts(charts2){
 var IndicatorCharts=charts2.options;
 for (var b=1;b<=500;b++){
  if (document.getElementById(IndicatorCharts[b].value)){
   document.getElementById(IndicatorCharts[b].value).style.display=IndicatorCharts[b].selected?'block':'none';
  }
 }
}

</script>
</head>

<body>
<div style="width:800px;border:1px solid black">
Price Chart<select onchange="PriceCharts(this);">
<option value="" ></option>
<option value="PriceCharts1" >1 day</option>
<option value="PriceCharts2" >5 days</option>
</select>
</div>
</div>
<div style="width:800px;height:300px;border:1px solid black">

<div id="PriceCharts1" class="hide" >
Indicator Chart 1<select onchange="IndicatorCharts(this);">
<option value="" ></option>
<option value="IndicatorCharts1" >Indicator 1</option>
<option value="IndicatorCharts2" >Indicator 2</option>
</select>
<div style="height:250px;border:1px solid black">
1 day price chart
</div>
</div>

<div id="PriceCharts2" class="hide">
Indicator Chart 2<select onchange="IndicatorCharts(this);">
<option value=""></option>
<option value="IndicatorCharts3" >Indicator 3</option>
<option value="IndicatorCharts4" >Indicator 4</option>
</select>

<div style="height:250px;border:1px solid black">
5 day price chart
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Currently, the problem is I want the content of the second drop-down list, which is the "Indicator Chart" can replace the content of "Pirce Chart". For example, when I click "1 day" in the first drop-down list, the second drop-down list (1), which is the "Indicator Chart 1" and the "1 day price chart" will be shown in a div. If now I click "Indicator 1" in the "Indicator Chart 1" list, I want the "Indicator 1" replace the "1 day price chart". If I click the blank option in the "Indicator Chart 1" list, it will show back the "1 day price chart". And also, if I click any options in the "Price Chart", I would like the "Indicator Chart" in each option set its option to blank and always show the relevant price chart.

I know this is a bit complicated and troublesome...but it is very important to me guys. Please help me...I have searched the solution for the whole night......

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation is to use [jquery](http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page), it will make your life a lot easier (I've provided some links below).  Now, I am not positive this is what you are looking for, but let me know.  I have provided a [DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Mz4SN/54/) using jsfiddle.

CODE:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

<head>
  <title></title>

<style type="text/css">
div{
    width:800px;
    border:1px solid black;
    display:block;
}
#pcDiv{
    width:800px;
    border:1px solid black;
}
.content{
 height:250px;   
}
#priceChart1, #priceChart2, #indicatorChartInfo1, #indicatorChartInfo2{
 display:none;   
}

</style>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script  type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){   //MAKES SURE DOCUMENT IS READY
    $("#pcSelect").change(function() {   
        //.change(function(){ similar to ONCHANGE
        // WHEN USING JQUERY, MAKE SURE TO USE '$(this)' instead of 'this'
        //I also used filter/index to find which option was selected
      var index= $(this).children(":selected").index();
            if(index!=0){
               $("#pcDiv").siblings().hide();
               $("#priceChart" + index).show();
            }
            else{
                $("#pcDiv").siblings().hide();
            }
    });  

    $("#priceChart1>select, #priceChart2>select").change(function(){
        var index= $(this).children(":selected").index();
        $(this).siblings().show();

          if(index!=0){
              $(this).siblings().text($(this).children(":selected").text());
          }
          else{
                $(this).siblings().hide();
          }
    });
});​
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="pcDiv">
Price Chart   
    <select id="pcSelect">
        <option>--Choose--</option> <!--CAN SAY WHATEVER YOU LIKE -->
        <option>1 day</option>
        <option>5 days</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div id="priceChart1">
    Indicator Chart 1
    <select>
        <option></option>
        <option>Indicator 1</option>
        <option>Indicator 2</option>
    </select>

    <div id="indicatorChartInfo1" class="content">
    Info1
    </div>
</div>

<div id="priceChart2">
Indicator Chart 2
    <select>
        <option></option>
        <option>Indicator 3</option>
        <option>Indicator 4</option>
    </select>

    <div id="indicatorChartInfo2" class="content">
    Info2
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

LINKS:

- [jquery.com](http://www.jquery.com)
- [Tutorial](http://www.impressivewebs.com/jquery-tutorial-for-beginners/)

Comment: Thank you for answering me! There are a few problems here. 1. The code can run properly in  jsfiddle, but it does not work in dreamweaver. 2. For the function part, what I want is when I click "1 day" in the first drop-down list, not only show the second drop-down list, but also show "price graph 1" below the second drop-down list. Then when I click anything in the second drop-down list the content will replace the "price graph 1", which you have made it work. Thank you so much

Comment: Go to http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery and download the minified version (UNDER CURRENT VERSION). Then put that in your local scripts folder (or whatever you are using). Then make a reference to that script like so: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_src.asp.  Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you. How about the function part? Could you help me to fix it?

Comment: Make sure that script is called BEFORE the function.  Syntax $ means it's jquery.  This should help... http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C_SEzhieo_A

Comment: Sorry I didn't make myself clear just now. I mean the code you wrote is not exactly what I want, I have stated the problem in the first comment. Thank you so much

Comment: Try clicking "Multiscreen" (next to inspect) at the top of the screen in dreamweaver.  it should work.